# Bash command for >stdout and >stdout+stderr

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Under Linux/bash I want to run a command and send standard output to foo.txt as well as combined standard output and standard error to bar.txt:

```
$ cmd < input.txt  1>foo.txt 1+2>bar.txt   ???
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

To send just stdout is:

```
$ cmd > foo.txt
```

To send both stdout/stderr is:

```
$ cmd &> bar.txt
```

However trying to combine:

```
$ cmd > foo.txt &>bar.txt
```

Causes foo.txt to be empty.

Comment: Although `&>` does work as you describe in `bash`, please be aware that its use is non-standard.  Indeed, it can be argued that it violates the standard, although some claim the standard is ambiguous on this point.  It behaves quite differently in `dash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
(cmd | tee out.txt) &> both.txt
```

That'll redirect `stdout` to `out.txt` and both `stdout` and `stderr` to `both.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have two redirections of the output stream at the same time. Easiest way to do what you want is to pipe output to the [tee](http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html) command.

Comment: What would the command-line look like using the tee command in this case?